Adding tick marks to flexdashboard gauge
I would like to add tick marks on a flexdashboard guage plot and then highlight a specific point where the gauge bar would transition from success to danger. Here is my code so far:
flexdashboard::gauge(42, min = 0, max= 100, 
                     abbreviateDecimals = 2,
                     sectors = flexdashboard::gaugeSectors(success = c(0,50),
                                                           warning = c(50,75),
                                                           danger = c(75,100),
                                                           colors = c('green','yellow','red')))

Here's how it looks now

And I would like it to look something like this

Even if it doesn't look as clean as the second image it would be nice to have the tick marks on the plot and then have some way of highlighting the point at which the bar would change colors.

Recreated a similar gauge chart in Highcharter, as I don't think this is possible with flexdashboard::gauge(). You can play with the innerRadius and outerRadius of the plot bands to get them below the main gauge fill.

Code used to generate the plot:
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Value = 42)

hchart(
  df,
  hcaes(y = Value),
  name = "Value",
  type = "solidgauge",
  radius = 93,
  dataLabels = list(
    borderWidth = 0,
    padding = 0,
    y = -20,
    style = list(
      fontWeight = "bold",
      fontSize = "60px")
  )
) |>
  hc_pane(
    startAngle = -120,
    endAngle = 120,
    background = list(
      backgroundColor = "lightgrey",
      borderWidth = 0,
      outerRadius = '100%',
      innerRadius = '60%',
      shape = "arc"
    )
  ) |>
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(
      text = ""
    ),
    min = 0,
    max = 100,
    minorTicks = FALSE,
    tickWidth = 0,
    lineWidth = 0,
    offset = -15,
    labels = list(
      style = list(
        fontSize = "1.2em",
        color = "lightgrey"),
      distance = 35
    ),
    plotBands = list(
      list(
        from = 0,
        to = 50,
        color = "green"
      ),
      list(
        from = 50,
        to = 75,
        color = "yellow"
      ),
      list(
        from = 75,
        to = 100,
        color = "red"
      )
    )
  ) |>
  hc_chart(style = list(fontFamily = "Source Sans Pro")) |>
  hc_colors(colors = case_when(
    df$Value < 51 ~ "green",
    df$Value < 76 ~ "yellow",
    .default = "red"
  ))


Not sure if it's possible with guage(), but an alternative might be to add a ggplot() using coord_radial() to the dashboard (something along these lines)?
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(
  x = c(1:42, 1:50, 51:75, 76:100), 
  y = c(rep(1, 42), rep(0.1, 50), rep(0.1, 25), rep(0.1, 25)),
  col = c(rep("darkgreen", 42), rep("darkgreen", 50), rep("darkorange", 25), rep("darkred", 25))
  )

df |> ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = col, colour = col)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.8) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1, colour = "white") +
  annotate("text", label = "42", x = 50, y = -0.5, size = 10, fontface = "bold") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), n.breaks = 10) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, NA)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_colour_identity() +
  coord_radial(start = -0.5 * pi, end = 0.5 * pi, expand = FALSE) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
    )


Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.1.0
